# Setting status conditions for controller-runtime's client Get errors

Tags: kubernetes, kubebuilder

Under which conditions will client.Client return a non-nil error and the client object will be also filled (or at least the namespace and name object meta)? The Kubernetes operator framework book suggests to [set a status condition](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/The-Kubernetes-Operator-Framework-Book/blob/main/chapter_05/controllers/nginxoperator_controller.go#L71) in case of getting resource errors in a similar fashion:

```golang
myResource := &v1alpha1.MyResource{}
err := r.Get(ctx, req.NamespacedName, myResource)
if err != nil && errors.IsNotFound(err) {
    return ctrl.Result{}, nil
} else if err != nil {
    logger.Error(err, "Error getting resource object")
    meta.SetStatusCondition(&myResource.Status.Conditions, metav1.Condition{
        Type:               "Failed",
        Status:             metav1.ConditionTrue,
        Reason:             "NotAvailable",
        LastTransitionTime: metav1.NewTime(time.Now()),
        Message:            fmt.Sprintf("unable to get custom resource: %s", err.Error()),
    })
    return ctrl.Result{}, utilerrors.NewAggregate([]error{err, r.Status().Update(ctx, myResource)})
}
```

Is it even possible to update the status of a CR where we are unable to get it, but the error doesn't satisfy the condition `errors.IsNotFound(err)`?

Comment: Refer to this [doc](https://book-v1.book.kubebuilder.io/basics/simple_controller.html) helpful to resolve your issue

Comment: Hi @Sai Chandini Routhu I'm aware about the approach in the kubebuilder book, but what confuses me is the approach in the above mentioned book. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [list of errors](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/master/pkg/api/errors/errors.go) you may get from reconciler's `Get()` method.

If the error is not nil, that means **you most probably did not get the resource correctly, so you shouldn't update it**. Say that your error is `TooManyRequests`. In this case, `errors.IsTooManyRequests(err)` returns `true` while `errors.IsNotFound(err)` returns `false`. The point is, there is no guarantee that you have the correct version of the custom resource if the `err` is not `nil`. You should return the error and let the controller reconcile it again.